# TortoiseSVN unable to remove conflict markers?

Tags: version-control, tortoisesvn

I know this may sound silly but it seems that, my version of TortoiseSVN is unable to resolve conflicts even for text files. I've followed the manual to the letter (By selecting`Edit Conflicts` the resolving the conflict via Winmerge, and then, selecting `Resolved`), but when I viewed the text file, the conflict markers are still there. Is this the expected result? I may be missing something here, but I was expecting the conflict markers to be removed after I did the steps the the previous statement. I thought it maybe winmerge not properly saving, so i tried to upgrade it, but to no avail. I also tried using Araxis merge but also no luck. I think I'm just missing something here but what?

BTW the ff. are the versions of my programs

TortoiseSVN

```
TortoiseSVN 1.6.7, Build 18415 - 32 Bit , 2010/01/22 17:55:06
Subversion 1.6.9, 
apr 1.3.8
apr-utils 1.3.9
neon 0.29.3
OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
zlib 1.2.3
```

WinMerge

```
Winmerge Version 2.12.4.0
```

This the configuration for Winmerge in my TortoiseSVN

```
[WinmergePath] -e -x -ub -dl %bname -dr %yname %base %mine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try it with TortoiseMerge (the merge program included with TortoiseSVN)? In TortoiseMerge, be sure to save first, then click Resolved inside TortoiseMerge.

Comment: Looks like the solution was right under my nose hehe... sigh.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen with my .cs files. There are times when I have to delete the directory contents and update my side again. Even when it meant that I would have to re-apply some of my changes. Like saving anything you are working on, doing intermittent updates will ensure that you have little work to redo should something fail.

Comment: That's just what we're doing now to work around this problem. Still trying to find a solution though. Thanks for the info!